# Uploaded avatar image only appears on hover

Tags: support, profile-picture, gravatar, user-card

My uploaded avatar image only appears when I hover over it.

Normal:

[image]

Hover:

[image]

Comment: Uploaded where? Gravatar? They seem to have real problems these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Gravatar for your image. Gravatar is having a lot of issues with their CDN the past few months, and regularly drop the ball when generating different sizes of your image. In your case the 32x32 size image is the generated image rather than your chosen picture but other sizes are fine.

The work-around is to upload the Marcel Proust photograph directly to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yep, that's it. Just uploaded it as an image and all seems fine.

Comment: Also, well spotted :-)